# PromQL change label value (not name) into a specific metric in all TSDB

Tags: label, prometheus, grafana, metrics, promql

I would like to change the *value* (not the label name) of label `instance` in the Prometheus DB using a PromQL from metric `rundeck_system_stats_uptime_since`.

[image: Grafana screenshot]

I managed to do this before ingestion using this:

```
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name,__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number]
          action: replace
          separator: ":"
          target_label: instance
```

So I'm covered for future metrics, but I would like to do this for existing values for `instance` label.

Expected result:

```
rundeck_system_stats_uptime_since{app="rdk-exporter", instance="rdk-exporter:9620", [...]}
```

Since it's a container in k8s I'm not interested in the IP of that container/host/node etc. because it's always changing, I'm only interested in the metrics.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `label_replace` from [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace)

How it is work you can check [in victoriametrics play](https://play.victoriametrics.com/select/accounting/1/6a716b0f-38bc-4856-90ce-448fd713e3fe/prometheus/graph/?g0.expr=label_replace(process_cpu_seconds_total%7Binstance%3D%7E%22.*%3A8429%22%7D%2C%20%22instance%22%2C%20%22some%3A%242%22%2C%20%20%22instance%22%2C%20%22(.*)%3A(.*)%22)&g0.range_input=12h%2040m%20827ms&g0.end_input=2022-06-30T21%3A28%3A58&g0.relative_time=none&g0.step_input=108.573&g1.expr=process_cpu_seconds_total%7Binstance%3D%7E%22.*%3A8429%22%7D&g1.range_input=12h%2040m%20827ms&g1.end_input=2022-06-30T21%3A28%3A58&g1.relative_time=none&g1.step_input=108.573)

So for example I have three metrics

```
process_cpu_seconds_total{cluster_num="1"cluster_retention="1m"instance="play-1m-1-vmagent.us-east1-b.c.victoriametrics-test.internal:8429"job="vmagent"}
process_cpu_seconds_total{cluster_num="1"cluster_retention="accounting"instance="play-accounting-1-vmagent.us-east1-b.c.victoriametrics-test.internal:8429"job="vmagent"}
process_cpu_seconds_total{cluster_num="1"cluster_retention="admin"instance="play-admin-1-vmagent.us-east1-b.c.victoriametrics-test.internal:8429"job="vmagent"}
```

if I will use this query

```
label_replace(process_cpu_seconds_total{instance=~".*:8429"}, "instance", "some:$2", "instance", "(.*):(.*)")
```

I will get next response

```
process_cpu_seconds_total{cluster_num="1"cluster_retention="1m"instance="some:8429"job="vmagent"}
process_cpu_seconds_total{cluster_num="1"cluster_retention="accounting"instance="some:8429"job="vmagent"}
process_cpu_seconds_total{cluster_num="1"cluster_retention="admin"instance="some:8429"job="vmagent"}
```

where instance will have same host.

Hope this solution will help you.

Comment: I did as you said but it does not work. I receive an ok query result but the older values are still there https://imgur.com/PwdtoOi

Comment: What do you mean older values are still there?

Comment: If I query for metrics from December, nothing has changed